# Error binding IAM policy when setting up cloud functions with endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following [these](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) instructions to setup a Google Cloud Endpoints with Cloud functions.

I've managed to setup ESP with Cloud Run, and configured the endpoint, but now at the point where I binding an IAM policy to grant ESP permission to invoke the cloud functions.

The error comes when calling this:

```
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
    --member "serviceAccount:ESP_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" \
    --project FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.add-iam-policy-binding) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Bad Request], message=[Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "options_requestedPolicyVersion": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'options_requestedPolicyVersion' could not be found in request message.]
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest CLI: `gcloud components update`.

Comment: Yep I have already done that. Still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I recommend creating a new Cloud Functions issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559729

Comment: OK, submitted now

Comment: Can you share the Cloud Functions Issue link?

Comment: @JC98 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139883142

Comment: Same issue here, I tried to set the role directly from the console on the compute engine default service account, which seems to work but 1- I never got to choose which CF I allow it to execute and 2- actual http requests on my endpoints service return a 503

Comment: Looks like this was broken in 259.0.0.  Roll back to 258.0.0 and it'll work:

command --   `gcloud components update core --version 258.0.0`

Comment: You can grand the permission manually on console https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this was a bug, and has now been updated by the Google dev team.